# Why do current and electrons flow in opposite directions?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

In representing an electric circuit, we would draw the sense of the current from the positive to the negative pole and the electrons from the negative to the positive .
But as I know electrons' motion create current.
So how is this possible?